# Blocking off text with blank lines in Sphinx (python)

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm looking to include program usage in a Sphinx document, but am having trouble enclosing the text in a block.

There are blank spaces in my text.  Example:

**Proper usage of script.py**

```
  usage: script.py [-h] [-q] [-v] [-D DAYS] [-H HOURS] [-M MINUTES] [-x] -s
                     SERVER -d DATABASE -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD

  Run some funky stuff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of options here depending on what you want:

- [Code Blocks](http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/code.html#showing-code-examples)
- [Block Quotes](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#block-quotes)
- [Line Blocks](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#line-blocks)